# Good holiday gifts for poker players?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I run a poker discussion group where we all get together and talk about hands and help each other out with our games. It's a relatively new group but it's getting a lot of success. I consistently get anywhere from 10-12 people that come together and work on our skils. It's going great right now!

So I want to do a holiday gift for the people in the group. What is the best poker-related gift you've received? I don't want anything obvious like card protectors. Maybe a nice water bottle? Or what else could you use during games/tournaments that would be a good group gift?

Comment: So what did you get them?

Comment: @Jon I decided to go with custom aluminum water bottles. I got the ones that are laser-etched they are NOT printed, so (I think) they are going to look pretty classy (they should arrive next week). I found a custom bottle company that was having a Black Friday sale, so each bottle is costing me less than $6 - I ordered 25 of them and they were very affordable. The bottles are red and etched with the name of our group. I'll post a pic here as soon as they come in.

Comment: very cool, I will keep an eye out for them.

Comment: @Jon the gift I chose arrived today and I posted an answer below with a picture of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I promised to post a picture of the gift I got my group. I've attached it to this answer. Poker Church is the name of our group and it's an aluminum bottle that is laser etched, so it looks pretty classy! :) The lighting in the pic makes it look more pink than it is - the bottle is a really nice shade of red.

[image: Poker Church]

Answer (score 2):

Group logo wear, t-shirts or hats. Cool stuff at the table.

Comment: I like the spirit of this answer, but IMO one of the last things you want to do at the table is signal to people that you try to study and think about the game.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer this is both a good question and a good comment - both make sense! I'm trying to stay away from clothing because I then have to worry about sizes, male/female styles, etc, etc. I'm hoping to find something a little "easier" than that.

Answer (score 2):

I would love the idea of a "group chip". A customized chip with your group logo or something. You know, you carry this chip easily with you meaning you belong to this group.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a challenge coin. I like that, thank you for the idea